# Getting a correct date by adding substracting a number of milliseconds

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Today is 18/12/2013.

I was testing this program where I wanted get another date by adding/substracting a number of milliseconds from `System.currentMillis()`. It works well when I shift the date in decembre but it doesn't work correctly for some similar values. For example the following code gives me  `2013 12 20`   as the result! I wonder, no I still wonder how it could be possible! or I'm making a mistake?

```
public class CreateDirFiles {


    public static final String PLOG_DIR = "ProductLog";

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter  = new SimpleDateFormat();

    public CreateDirFiles() {
    }

    public void createDayDir(Date date){
        dateFormatter.applyPattern("YYYY");
        String year = dateFormatter.format(date);
        dateFormatter.applyPattern("MM");
        String month = dateFormatter.format(date);
        dateFormatter.applyPattern("dd");
        String day = dateFormatter.format(date);
        System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", year, month, day);
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        CreateDirFiles dfc = new CreateDirFiles();
        dfc.createDayDir(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() -
                ((long)( 48 * 24 * 3600 * 1000)) ));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. Use `Calendar` instead.

Comment: Anyway it should work well new Date(millis) is not deprecated yet! Using date or calendar isn't the topic.

Comment: No, it will not work with Date because Date has no way of adding/substracting time. Calendar does.

Comment: And once I create the date instance I will never ever need to change it. I wanted to test Java.io not Date! This error was accidental. I want to understand what the problem is!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
((long)( 48 * 24 * 3600 * 1000))
```

That's doing all the arithmetic in 32 bits, and then converting the (now truncated, as the result is too large for an `int`) result to a `long`. You want:

```
48L * 24 * 3600 * 1000
```

where the `L` suffix means that it'll use a long for the value 48.

However, you *really* don't want to do this at all - you want to use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) which is a *much* nicer API for date/time work. You really don't want to have to mess around with the low level stuff at all.

```
LocalDate date = ...;
LocalDate twoDaysLater = date.minusDays(48);
```

If you *really* want to stick with the built-in API, then use `Calendar`. At the *very least* use the `TimeUnit` enum, which will allow:

```
long millisFor48Days = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(48);
```

You also need to consider the time zone - while "today" may be the 18th of December for you, it isn't elsewhere in the world.

Comment: Which should be avoided if he had simply used `Calendar` instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @m0skit0: Or Joda Time, as I've now recommended.

Comment: I like JodaTime better too but it also means an extra dependency.

Comment: but now he learned something more important than using calendar instead of date.

Comment: @m0skit0: What's likely to be more expensive - one dependency, or the horror of using java.util.Calendar?

Comment: @m0skit0 Can you immagine please that I'm working with Java 2 in spite of 7! I told you that I was testing some java.io functionalities! I know very well that calendar does everything for me.

Comment: @Johnny: java.util.Calendar has been present since Java 1.1.

Comment: @Johnny What has java.io to do with the code you posted? Nothing. I'm answering your question, I don't have to guess whatever strange stuff you **want** to do. Anyway, I hope you learned not to try to reinvent the wheel. If not, well, I cannot say anything more.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I didn't know it and I thought that it has been added since Java5

Comment: @m0skit0 I hadn't still implemented the rest. You are right but it was very important to me to understand why it didn't work like that. I had written in the question " I wonder, no I still wonder how it could be possible! or I'm making a mistake?". It shows what was important with that bug for me!

Comment: I saw "milliseconds" in the title and "Jon Skeet" as last active user, so I knew you would be recommending Joda Time. In every answer you give on time-related questions, you recommend Joda Time. :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: That's not at all true. In .NET-based questions, I recommend Noda Time instead!